# const fs = require('fs') is empty in NW.js

Tags: node.js, node-modules, node-webkit

`const fs = require('fs');` returns empty in NW.js.

Reading the NW.js documentation, I saw that this issue can be resolved using `const fs = nw.require('fs');`

BUT, in my case, I use an npm module that calls fs internally, in which case it would not be possible to change the module. It would be a bad practice!

How to make NW.js work `require('js')` without `nw.require`?

Comment: I abandoned NW.js, now I use Electron.js